# Oracle Sql Query having error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select loc 
from emp e, 
     dept d 
having count(e.deptno) = 0 
    or sal <= min(sal) 
   and d.dname = 'SALES' 
   and count(ename) >=2 
   and sal < avg(sal) 
group by loc 
where e.deptno != d.deptno;
```

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I get this error when I run this command on oracle, can anyone help me resolve this error?

Comment: Start with a simple join, then add one thing at the time.

Comment: This query is a mess (even when you move the WHERE in the right position). What are you actually trying to return?

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the usage of having clause and where clause.

Having clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

For further info check :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2130020

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is at the wrong position, try

```
    select loc
      from emp e, dept d
     where e.deptno != d.deptno
     having count(e.deptno) = 0 or sal <= min(sal) and d.dname = 'SALES' and count(ename) >= 2 and sal < avg(sal)
     group by loc
    ;
```